# Hibernate caching for projections

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, caching, jpql

I use JPA for persistence with caching (Hibernate and Redis).

I have several tables with multiple columns.
In most cases I just need to retrieve several columns only. However, the business logic queries contain multiple joins and complex filtering conditions.

I am thinking about implementing the business logic using either JPQL, or Criteria API or native queries. Native queries attract me most as I could use window functions and other DB-specific features.
I have only concern about caching efficiency. For the queries containing subset of fields (projections) would Hibernate used cached entities?

I believe, not, the only cache would be at the query level.
So for this case there are no benefits of using JPQL or criteria API in terms of performance, caching, or something else... and I can use direct native queries here with "cacheable" param set to "true".

Could you please confirm or disprove my understanding?

Comment: Why do you need caching? Isn't the DB fast enough?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  I want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if you are not fetching entities but projections, the entity caching won't help you. You can still use query caching, but the invalidation is very coarse grained, so you might not see big benefits. I would suggest you avoid caching unless you have no other option as there are many things that can go wrong. A database is, when using proper indexes, usually fast enough to handle all requests and often it's easier to just scale up the database than implementing complex caching on top.

Having said that, I can only recommend you take a look at [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which allows you to model projections as interfaces.

Blaze-Persitence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model(window functions as well). I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

An entity view that uses window functions could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(Order.class)
public interface OrderTotalPriceDTO {
    Long getId();
    String getCustomer();
    @Mapping("SUM(orderLines.totalPrice)")
    BigDecimal getTotalPrice();
    @Mapping("SUM(SUM(orderLines.totalPrice)) OVER (ORDER BY orderDate)")
    BigDecimal getCummulativeTotalPrice();
}
```

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features